# Чи є відмінності у вживанні слів "запитання" та "питання"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

> **Це запитання також має відповідь (англійською):**
>   *[What is the difference between питання, запит, and запитання?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1225)*

Чи є відмінності та особливості вживання слів *запитання* та *питання*?

Також цікаво, як правильно: *запитати*, *задати питання* чи *поставити запитання*?

Якщо на хвилинку уявити, що цей сайт буде локалізовано українською, то яким буде переклад верхнього меню *Questions* - *Запитання* чи *Питання*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Рубрика ["Уроки державної мови"](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/66.htm) газети "Хрещатик" пояснює різницю так.

> Семантичні відмінності є також у слів *питання* та *запитання*.
>
> Перше з них (**питання**) уживаємо тоді, коли йдеться про якусь
>   справу, проблему, що потребує розв’язання чи дослідження; пункт
>   документа, порядку денного. Найчастіше воно виступає у сполученні з
>   дієсловом порушувати, рідше — ставити, висувати (в значенні
>   “пропонувати для обговорення, вивчення”). Але заміну порушувати на
>   піднімати (“Доповідач піднімав важливі питання...”) в сучасній
>   літературній мові сприймають як стилістично невдалу.
>
> У граматичній термінології також уживається питання, а не запитання.
>   Знак питання, а не знак запитання, питальне речення, а не запитальне.
>
> **Запитання** — це звернення до кого-небудь, щоб з’ясувати щось; вимога, прохання з приводу чогось; запит. “Несподіване запитання
>   Богдана збентежило Гордія” (Дмитро Ткач). Кореспонденція на пошту
>   надходить “до вимоги” її адресатом, або до запитання.
>
> Запитанням може бути і звернення, яке не потребує відповіді. То так
>   зване риторичне запитання — прийом красномовства, художній засіб
>   образної мови.
>
> Не можна поєднувати іменник *запитання* з дієсловом задавати, для
>   цього є більш прийнятне *ставити*: “Капітан сміється, а Ліна Яцуба, не
>   зводячи з нього своїх серйозних очей, ставить йому своє запитання”
>   (Олесь Гончар). У значенні “звернення, що потребує відповіді” не слід
>   уживати замість запитання слово питання, бо це суперечить мовним
>   нормам.

2. Сайт ["Мова - ДНК нації"](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/zapitannya-y-pitannya) візуалізує.
3. Олександр Авраменко у своєму [Експрес-уроці](https://tsn.ua/video/video-novini/ekspres-urok-ukrayinskoyi-movi-pitannya-chi-zapitannya.html) пояснює так.

Comment: Не пояснюєте наявність префіксу за-. Я не розумію.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, здається, sashaeve цікавився відмінностями у вживанні, а не словотворенням.

Comment: Oksana Gubrenko Вибачте, але на основі вказаних пояснень мені не достатньо того, щоб зрозуміти різницю між словами питання та запитання. Тобто як їх вживати. Це стосується пояснень на цій сторінці та усіх інших, що я знайшов в мережі. Пояснення не чіткі для мене. Думаю, що проблема саме в розумінні префікса за-. Також перечитав тлумачні словники та інші джерела. Немає зрозумілого для мене тексту.

Comment: @ Oksana Gubrenko На основі чого ґрунтується твердження "Не можна поєднувати іменник запитання з дієсловом задавати"?

Comment: Як правильно вказати ваше ім'я з @, щоб працювало?

Comment: З прочитаного зрозумів, що є слово питання і є слово запитав, але слова запитання схоже просто не правильне. Тобто воно не логічне. ... для мене.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, не розумію Ваших претензій до мене. Про підстави для тверджень (Ваш 3-ій коментар), то це радше питання до автора цитати. Ви кажете, що перечитали тлумачні словники та інші джерела, тож якщо маєте інше бачення, можете оформити його альтернативною відповіддю. Я намагалась відповісти запитувачу. Складно врахувати всі можливі дотичні запитання від інших учасників SE. Тег на ім*я в цьому конкретному випадку не працює, бо я і є автор відповіді, яку коментують, тому повідомлення мені приходить за вмовчанням.

Comment: Надіявся, що зможете пояснити детальніше ...

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, даруйте, що неправильно зрозуміла. Стосовно Ваших припущень у коментарі "З прочитаного...", мені, навпаки, здається цілком логічно: питати -> питання, запитати -> запитання.  Утім, якщо все ж є сумніви, можете оформити як окреме запитання з акцентом саме на цьому нюансі.

Answer (score 6):

Відповідно до Словника української мови:

[ЗАПИТА́ННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapytannja)

> **ЗАПИТА́ННЯ**, я, сер.
>
> 1. **Звертання до кого-небудь з метою з'ясування чогось; питання**. — Відповідайте на запитання точно (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 282);
>
> //  **Те, що вимагає з'ясування**.  — Коли з'являться у вас
>   запитання... виникнуть якісь непорозуміння ...або надибаєте на
>   чудернацькі речі чи там перешкоди, прошу негайно до мене (Юрій
>   Шовкопляс, Людина.., 1962, 276);
>
> //  **Тема для відповіді при перевірці знань учня, при збиранні
>   якихось відомостей і т. ін**.  Олександра Василівна роздала запитання,
>   які будуть на іспитах з російської та української мов (Олесь Донченко,
>   IV, 1957, 503)
>
> *Ставити запитання* див. ставити.
>
> 2. **Вимога, прохання дати які-небудь відомості або офіційне роз'яснення з приводу чого-небудь; запит** (у 1 знач.).  Член партії
>      має право: ..звертатися з запитаннями, заявами і пропозиціями в
>      будь-яку партійну інстанцію, аж до ЦК КПРС, і вимагати відповіді по
>      суті свого звернення (Статут КПРС, 1961, 6).
>
>    *До запитання* - який видається особисто адресатові на його вимогу
>      (про лист, пакунок і т. ін.).

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 3, 1972. — Стор. 256.

[ПИТА́ННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pytannja)

> **ПИТА́ННЯ**, я, сер.
>
> 1. **Звертання до кого-небудь, яке потребує відповіді, роз'яснення і т. ін.**  Ми, вбившись у гурт, намагались відповісти Жабі на її запити і самі засипали її
>      питаннями (Олесь Досвітній, Вибр., 1959, 159).
>
> ▲ *Знак питання* — розділовий знак, який застосовується на письмі для
>   вираження запитання, сумніву, вагання.
>
> *Риторичне питання* див.риторичний.
>
> ♦ *Загострювати (загострити) питання* див. загострювати; *Задавати
>   (задати) питання* див. задавати; *Піднімати (підняти) питання* див.
>   піднімати; *Ставити питання [руба]* див. ставити; *Що за питання!* —
>   цілком зрозуміло; саме так.
>
> 2. **яке, про кого — що. Положення, справа, предмет, які вимагають розв'язання, обговорення, уваги і т. ін.** Коли вже зачепили всі
>      питання Про бога й про посмертне проживання, То й я вам думку висловлю
>      свою (Леся Українка, 1, 1951, 98);
>
> *Жіноче питання* див. жіночий.
>
> ♦ *Болюче питання* див. болючий; *Гостре питання* див. гострий.
>
> 3. **чого. Справа або обставина, що стосується чого-небудь або залежить від чогось.** Хіть напала мандрувати, Аж молодшає чуття; Годі
>      ум багнітувати Над питаннями життя (Павло Грабовський, I, 1959, 193);

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 6, 1975. — Стор. 367.

Comment: Хм, "питання" - гарний переклад для "issue" :)

Answer (score 1):

Ось як пояснює семантичну відмінність посібник Є. Чак "Чи правильно ми говоримо?" (1997):

**Запитання** — це словесне звернення, яке потребує відповіді або є риторичним:

> «— Але перед цим дозвольте кілька ***запитань***, — сказав один інспектор».
>   (О. Довженко.)

Слово **питання** здебільшого вживають, коли йдеться про якусь проблему, справу, що потребує розв'язання або вивчення:

> «Довго билася наука над 
>   ***питанням***, як же зробити рослини міцнішими, щоб
>   не вимерзали, багатші на плоди стали, як схрестити їх?» (О. Довженко.)

У граматичній термінології вживають слово **питання**, а не запитання. Наприклад, питання, на які відповідають відмінки, члени речення. Так само знак *питання* (?), а не знак запитання, *питальне* речення, а не запитальне.

Отже, якщо йдеться про якусь проблему, що потребує розв'язання чи дослідження (а також у граматиці), вживають слово **питання**; коли мають на увазі звернення, що потребує відповіді або пояснень, краще надавати перевагу слову **запитання**.

Comment: А як стосовно питань/запитань у вікторині?