# «(За/с)питати (за)питання» — чи можна так казати?

Tags: значення-слів, стилістика

Колись мене довго привчали, що російською мовою не можна казати «спросить вопрос» — «спитати запитання». Що спитати (запитати) можна когось (наприклад, людину: «часом дівчата питали *Інну* в училищі…»), а саме (за)питання ставлять/задають, а не питають/запитують.

Чи є таке ж обмеження в українській мові?

Comment: порівняйте з суржиковим: остановіть на зупинці \ зупинить на останівці :)

Comment: Пропозиція. Можливо, варто підняти проблему на Meta або навіть глобальна Meta. Заголовок цього запитання не піддається пошуку за контекстом — по слову [**«запитати»**](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) взагалі, а по слову [**«спитати»**](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) знаходить тіло, але не заголовок. Причина — markup. Пропоную (1) якось переписати заголовок ; (2) обговорити на нашій Meta, як ми хочемо з цим боротися; (3) за висновками, підняти тему на Meta.SE. Що скажете?

Comment: @bytebuster, тут пошук взагалі через ****, як я бачу, працює. Наприклад, [пошук «питати»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=питати) не знаходить [«питав»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=питав). [Лематизації](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation), чи то навіть [стемінгу](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стемінг), нема. По-моєму, це мало б бути пріоритетнішою проблемою, але, з іншого боку, я не знаю, чи ми можемо на це вплинути. Щодо конкретно цієї проблеми — я б її вирішував так, що **повні форми** мають міститися в тілі. [Тут](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/646/4) я це врахував.

Comment: @bytebuster, ну і, якщо вважаєте, що потрібно створити цю тему в ме́ті — звісно, створюйте. Я не знаю, чи це опитування потрібно в ме́ті, але, по-моєму, ме́та — значно краще місце для таких обговорень, ніж коментарі. Моя особиста думка — не варто ускладнювати назву заради пошуку, а от тіло — варто.

Answer (score 7):

Це тавтологія:

> ТАВТОЛОГІЯ [грец. ταυτολογία — повторення, від ταυτό (τό αυτό) — те
>   саме і λογος — слово] — неусвідомлюваний, мимовільний або, навпаки,
>   навмисний повтор у межах словосполучення, речення того самого чи
>   однокорен. слів (формально-семантична Т.) або різнокорен. слів з
>   тотожним, аналогічним і под. значенням (семантична Т.).

[Звідси](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um111.htm)

Згідно культури мовлення, запитання ставлять, когось запитують.

Comment: Дуже дякую за відповідь. Але я хотів почути не про тавтологію. Я хотів зрозуміти про семантику перехідного дієслова «(за/с)питати» взагалі — чи може в принципі його об'єктом виступати іменник «(за)питання» (навіть най це тавтологія)? Чи об'єктом цього перехідного дієслова може бути лише людина, до якої звертаються. Тобто я розумію, що «(за/с)питати (за)питання» — тавтологія, але чи має така фраза сенс взагалі? Хоча це, мабуть, моя проблема, що я недолуго сформулював своє питання.

Answer (score 7):

Це запитання висвітлює проблему, яка називається «перехідні дієслова».

**Перехідне дієслово** виражає дію, спрямовану на *об'єкт*, виражений у реченні прямим додатком, іменною частиною мови у знахідному відмінку (Noun Phrase in Accusative case, або скорочено NP.ACC).

Наприклад, англійською дієслово *"to ask"* може керувати як *об'єктом* *"question"*, так і *об'єктом*–особою, яку запитують:

> *To ask **a question** about…*
>   *To ask **John** about…*

В українській мові, на відміну від англійської, дієслово *запитувати* є перехідним в контексті **запитувати особу**:

> *Я запитала **антикварія** про ціну книжки* — Леся Українка

Також вживається скорочена форма: *«запитувати про щось»*, але завжди мається на увазі, що об'єктом є **особа**, яку запитують, а не запитання, про яке йдеться.

---

Натомість, дієслово *поставити* цілком може керувати об'єктом *«(за-)питання»*.
Але ще варто враховувати різницю між *«питання»* і *«запитання»*, про яке докладно обговорено тут:
[Чи є відмінності у вживанні слів "запитання" та "питання"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/472/)

Comment: Насправді ще можна питати поради/згоди (хоча не впевнений, що це з.в.), квитки/пропуск/урок і дорогу/ціни/адресу/думку/сіль/чашку/кефір/контакти/квартиру (принаймні так вживається в літературі) — хоча, в цілому, думаю, Ви праві.