# Велика чи мала літера: (Д/д)ень (С/с)вятого Валентина, (Д/д)ень усіх закоханих?

Tags: велика-мала-літера

Якими правилами визначається написання з великої чи малої літери слів в назвах свят:

- поздоровляю з днем святого валентина;
- поздоровляю з днем усіх закоханих?

Comment: До речі, то ще питання, як правильно - "поздоровляю" чи "вітаю"? Особисто мені "поздоровляю" ріже вуха. Може мені варто було б запитати це окремим питанням?

Comment: @moudrick, **[давно](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/650/4)** (про «ріже слух» див. *[цю серію коментів](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/651/4#comment1667_651#comment1667_651)* — може, їх слід на окрему відповідь перетворити, як вважаєте?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Цей допис](http://velyka-chy-mala-litera.wikidot.com/dodatok3#toc16) містить доволі повний перелік граматичних правил, які встановлюють правопис назв дат і подій.

У даному випадку, ключовим правилом є те, чи є ця дата *індивідуалізованою і календарною* (регулярно відбувається з деяким інтервалом).

---

## Як писати слово «день»

Велика та мала літери в назвах історичних подій, епох, пам’яток, **назвах календарних дат**:

- З великої літери пишемо **індивідуалізовані найменування**:

  - **календарних та історичних дат і свят**: *День Європи, День Збройних сил України, День знань, […], День прав людини, День Руху неприєднання, Новий рік*

    - але у назвах церковно-календарних свят: *день Преподобного Антонія Печерського, день Великомучениці Катерини та ін.*;
- З малої літери пишемо родові найменування або його складники:

  - історичних подій та **епох**: *доба феодалізму, золотий вік, космічний вік*;
  - **некалендарних дат**: *день відчинених дверей, день зустрічі випускників, день інформації, санітарний день та ін.*

Окремо варто зауважити, що Валентин — це один із [ранньохристиянських святих](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD).

Отже, можна вважати обидва правописи вірними:

- Якщо вважати цей день — церковним святом, то з малої літери: *день Валентина* або *день Святого Валентина* .
- Якщо вважати, що у цей день святкується *День закоханих* (тобто, не зовсім те саме, що церковне свято), то тоді — з великої літери: *День Валентина*, *День Святого Валентина*.
- Те саме стосується правопису *«День закоханих»*: це регулярне календарне свято, тому *«День»* пишемо з великої літери.

---

## Як писати слово «святий»

Там же у секції [Велика та мала літери **в назвах людей**, істот і посад](http://velyka-chy-mala-litera.wikidot.com/dodatok3#toc7) вказується (2.б), що з великої літери пишуться індивідуальні позначення біблійних персонажів.
Тому — *Святий Валентин*.

Щоправда, як ми з'ясували вище, можна заперечити, що Святий Валентин у контексті Дня Валентина — це не зовсім біблійний персонаж. Тому, думаю, має право на існування і запис з малої літери: *святий Валентин*.