# Як правильно: День восьмого березня чи День Восьмого березня?

Tags: правопис, велика-мала-літера

Нещодавно вибирала вітальну листівку, щоб привітати з Міжнародним жіночим святом друзів та рідних і побачила мовний безлад. Назва свята у вітальних листівках, розміщених у мережі, пишеться по-різному:

- з днем 8 березня,
- з Днем 8 березня,
- День 8 Березня,
- День восьмого березня,
- День Восьмого березня.

Читаю статтю про свято. Знову бачу написання: Свято 8 березня виникло як день боротьби за права жінок у Нью-Йорку.

Вирішила знайти відповідь на питання: як писати правильно?

[Український правопис](http://pravopys.net/) дає відповідь на запитання:

> 22. Назви історичних подій, епох, війн, революцій, народно-визвольних рухів, повстань, революційних свят, знаменних дат і т. ін. пишуться з великої літери: Вели́ка францу́зька револю́ція…, Пе́рше тра́вня, Міжнаро́дний жіно́чий день, Нови́й рік, День учи́теля, День Незале́жності Украї́ни, Свя́то Перемо́ги.
>       Примітка 2. Якщо початковий порядковий числівник у складеній назві написаний цифрою, то наступне слово пишеться з великої літери: 8 Бе́резня, 1 Тра́вня.

Здається, зрозуміло, але сумніви залишаються, тому що немає точного прикладу із словом «день».

Читаю Вікіпедію — бачу лише приклади: 8 Березня і Восьме березня. Із словом «день»немає.

Словник-довідник «Велика чи мала літера» (В.В. Жайворонок) містить детальний список складених назв, що починаються словом «День». Серед них День Збройних сил України, День знань, День міліції, День Незалежності України, День Перемоги (Свято Перемоги, 9 Травня), День прав людини, День Руху неприєднання.  Такі приклади не дають впевненості у написанні назви вибраного свята.

Допоможіть, будь ласка, розібратись із написанням назва свята: що пишеться з великої літери, а що з малої?

Comment: Largely related or a duplicate of: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/646/

Answer (score 3):

Побудова назви свята "*день 8 Березня*" є не зовсім коректною. Означене число місяця вже є певним днем, тому виходить тавтологічна конструкція типу март-місяць, Дніпро-ріка... Назви свят, в яких застосовується слово День, не містять дати: *День Збройних сил, День юриста, День Перемоги, День народження* тощо.

Щодо решти діє правило правопису, наведене у запитанні. Якщо назва свята починається з числівника, то наступне слово пишеться з великої літери. Якщо писати прописом, то велика літера є лише у першому слові: Восьме березня. Можна ще сказати Свято 8 березня, тоді велика літера - знов-таки лише у першого слова.