# Як правильно привітати з днем народження?

Tags: велика-мала-літера

Мабуть кожен у своєму житті писав привітання з днем народження. У соціальних мережах безліч листівок на цю тему і майже на кожній з них слово ***"День"*** написано з великої літери. Та згідно з [чинними правилами правопису](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/ukrajinskij_pravopis_2007/pravopis_osnovi_slova/velika_litera_u_vlasnikh_nazvakh/12-1-0-327)
цей випадок не входить до тих, у яких хоч одне зі слів потрібно було б писати з великої букви.

Чи є якесь пояснення такої розбіжності між правилами і практичним вжитком? Може, є якісь точніші настанови, згідно з якими в певних випадках можна писати «з ***Днем*** народження», а в інших — «з ***днем*** народження»? Чи все-таки кожен, хто пише «з ***Днем*** народження», робить грубу помилку?

Comment: Традиційно звичайні загальні слова можуть писатися з великої літери [на знак великої пошани чи особливої уваги](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/ortoepia). Тож чинний правопис не вимагає писати з великої, але й не забороняє. (До речі, те, що Ви цитуєте — не «Правопис» 2015, а лише одна з його трактовок, у самому «Правописі» деталізація ще менша.)

Comment: @Sasha, перевідкрив у сподіванні, що хтось дасть відповідь, яка б суттєво відрізнялася від [Велика чи мала літера: (Д/д)ень (С/с)вятого Валентина, (Д/д)ень усіх закоханих?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/646/) та [Як правильно: День восьмого березня чи День Восьмого березня?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3188/)

Answer (score 6):

1. Ви правильно зазначили, що [чинний правопис **не** включає](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par38) "**день народження**" у список подій, назви яких пишуться з великої літери, адже це *не державне свято, не історична подія, не реліґійна подія.*
2. За правописом йде й [Авраменко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3AN_-aYy6M), але при цьому каже, що *у неформальному спілкуванні* для підкреслення поваги до людини, яку вітаєте, *можна написати "День народження" з великої літери*.
3. Білоус, Сербенська в "Екології українського слова" так само ставлять малу літеру:

> Вживають: з **д**ня народження. Правильно: від **д**ня народження.

4. Головащук у "Словнику-довіднику з українського літературного слововживання пише, що

> "День" у назвах свят пишеться з великої літери.

Це чи не єдина книга, яка не дає уточнення з приводу того, у назвах **яких** свят "День" пишеться з великої літери.

5. Гринчишин у "Словнику-довіднику з культури української мови" пише, що

> у назвах **знаменних дат** пишеться з великої літери.

День народження навряд чи можна долучити до знаменних дат.

Так, можна зробити висновок, що для офіційного й літературного вжитку треба писати **"день народження"** з ***малої літери***, але якщо ви хочете наголосити на своїй повазі до когось - у неформальному листуванні можна писати привітання з "Днем народження" з великої літери.