# What is the difference between питання, запит, and запитання?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

> **This question also has an answer here (in Ukrainian):**
>   *[Чи є відмінності у вживанні слів "запитання" та "питання"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/472)*

Google translate lists each as an alternate translation of the word "question." I've noticed that "запитання" is used in our tag descriptions. Each word seems to be based around the same root, but how do the prefixes alter its meaning?

Comment: I'm adding a header, according to a [discussion on Meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-our-stance-on-cross-language-duplicate-questions)

Comment: Also some language learners may misheard/misunderstand Ukrainian *питати* (to ask) as Russian *пытать* (to torture [somebody])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off — many, really many Ukrainian speakers do mix up *питання* and *запитання* (I do, in favor of a shorter one). So arguably, a language learner should not worry about making a mistake with these two words as well.

Basically, **питання** is *problem*, **запитання** is *question*, **запит** is *inquiry* (official request).

However,

- counter-intuitively, the question mark ("?") is *знак **питання***, not *знак запитання*;
- never use *{за}питати запитання* for "to ask a question"; use *ставити запитання* (or *поставити* for perfective aspect);
- for *питання*, as in "to raise a problem", use verb *підняти питання* or *порушити питання*;

The linked question in Ukrainian contains all necessary dictionary links.

Comment: Also in many cases "to ask a question" is just "запитати": "I want to ask you a question: ..." - "Хочу тебе запитати: ...".

Answer (score 8):

To clarify [the bytebuster's answer](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1226/4), *питання* and *запитання* are **not** disjoint.

*Питання* is a **hyperonym** of *запитання* (i.e. *питання* has all the meanings that *запитання* has with some additional ones; you can always substitute the word *запитання* in a text with the word *питання*, but substituting *питання* with *запитання* is only sometimes eligible). When Ukrainians use *питання* for "question" — it is **not** a mistake (still it is not the most accurate word for that).

In short:

- *запитання* — question;
- *питання* — question, problem/issue, matter;
- *запит* — inquiry (usually official or technical; e.g. official inquiry to state government or inquiry to database system).