# How did питати and пытать come to have such different meanings?

Tags: етимологія, from-russian, non-native-speaker

A comment on [this question of mine](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1225/259) alerted me to the difference.

Is this a case of the linguistic equivalent of "convergent evolution"? I don't see how that can happen with two languages as closely linked as Russian and Ukrainian.

Comment: I'm afraid that this Q is nearly offtopic as it is mostly about the Russian language. The Ukrainian word for "torture" is *тортури* (a calque from some Romance language — German?). The word `*pytaty` has equivalent meaning (of "to ask") in most Slavonic languages (see [Vasmer's dictionary](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)), and only in Russian it is different. Most certainly, we cannot answer why the Russians don't even make difference between "asking" and "torturing". An unknown socio-cultural phenomenon. :-)

Comment: Yeah should be closed as off-topic. This quesiton is more suited for Russian SE

Comment: @bytebuster i thought that *to ask* in Russian is *спросить* which is quite different from *пьітать*, so there is a difference for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, IMHO meanings of *питати* and *пытать* can be considered as relatively close. Although in most Slavic languages *питати* and similar words really mean something like “to ask”, but there are nuances:

- Russian — to torture, (colloquial) to try / to attempt / to check, (colloquial dated) to ask / to inquire / to question (*see [in Wiktionary](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Verb)*).
- Slovak, Moravian, Macedonian — to ask / to beg *(actually, I was unable to verify that the word really has “to beg”-like connotation through modern dictionaries, but, as [Vasmer's](//vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) and [Melnychuk's](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) etymological dictionaries both claim that, I suppose that at least it was partially true for that languages in some past times)*.
- Lower Sorbian, Upper Sorbian — to look for / to search / to find *(according to Melnychuk's etymological dictionary and* [pytaś *in Wiktionary*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pyta%C5%9B#Lower_Sorbian)*)*.

I consider first two entries in the above list to be approximately the same: simply the word got meaning of something like polite plea/supplication in some languages/dialects and of hard high-pressure interrogation in others; except that meaning in Russian was then somehow shifted to tortures (personally I suppose either “check” → “test/temptation (Christianity)” → “mental anguish/tortures” → “any tortures”, or “question” → “interrogation with tortures” → “tortures of any kind” path — though I don't have enough competence to make such assumptions reliably). It is not uncommon for Slavic languages to have diverging meanings for similar/cognate words, e.g. Russian *вонь* means “stink”/“stench” while Czech *vůně* means “fragrance” (pleasant sensation) or “smell” (neutral word).

Both Ukrainian *питати* and Russian *пытать* certainly derive from same origin (see Proto-Slavic *[*pytati](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/pytati)*). Modern usage of the root *пит*:

- Ukrainian:

  - words related to questions/requests/inquires: *допи́тливий* “curious”, [*питання*, *запитання*, *запит*](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1225), *опи́тувати* “to poll/survey“, *по́пит* “demand”;
  - still some minority of words per my opinion more relate to checks/attempts/trials rather than to questions/requests/inquires: *і́спит* “exam”, dated words: *[спит](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82&scope=ukrq&highlight=on)*, *[спи́ток](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82&scope=ukrq&highlight=on)*, *[по́спит](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82&scope=ukrq&highlight=on)*.
- In modern Russian, it is hard for me to somehow categorize *пыт*-words. Such words can have not only one of the three meanings mentioned in the beginning of this answer for *пытать* (although *пытать* tends to the 3rd, its cognates can refer to any of the following: (1) to ask / to inquire / to question, (2) to try / to attempt / to check, (3) to torture), but also some intermediate state between them. *Пытка* “torture”, *попытка* “attempt”, *пытаться* “to try”, *опыт* “experience”, *испытание* “test”, *испытывать* “to feel”, *пытливый* “curious”.

P.S.: No, I'd not call it “convergent evolution”. Convergent evolution — that's when some things with different natures/origins get similar traits due to influence of somewhat similar environments. I'd better say “convergent evolution” for Ukrainian *питати* and Russian *питать* (“to feed”); or for Ukrainian [*керувати* and *кермувати*](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/284). While in the case you've asked about it looks more like fork/divergence of Old East Slavic word.

Comment: There is also prominant example or different meanings: Ukrainian (and probably many slavic languages, at least Polish too) "вродливий" (=beautiful) and Russian "уродливый" (=ugly). Just in case you need such sample :)

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, ha, we're thinking in same direction :). `<!--Or examples of fully opposite sense: Russian _уродливый_` (commented part in the answer). But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ну, ні то й ні :) Також може бути цікаво: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фальшиві_друзі_перекладача