# Як перекласти з російської "Будут вопросы - задашь"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, соціолінгвістика

Як перекласти з російської "Будут вопросы - задашь"? Відомо, що:

1. Питання - це у сесійній залі. Їх порушують.
2. Запитання - на цьому сайті. Що з ними роблять?

Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська, [r2u.org.ua](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)) каже, що можна "ставити" запитання. Але якось не звучить. Ще гірше "завдавати", "спитати". Може хто знає краще?

Comment: [Будуть питання, звертайся!](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F&oq=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F&aqs=chrome..69i57.8681j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Занадто абстрактно. Моє запитання конкретніше.

Comment: Будуть питання  - задавай.

Comment: Відповідь на це запитання є серед відповідей тут: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/472/ Хоча це не прямий дублікат

Comment: Цей коментар тягне на відповідь, bytebuster♦ !

Comment: «Матимеш питання — питай!»

Comment: 1. Питання - у Раді.
2. Двічі корінь "питан".

Comment: Матимеш питання - звернешся.

Comment: Матимеш питання - запитаєш.

Comment: @Kosarar, не зовсім. «Питання» є гіперонімом (словом із ширшою множиною значень) до «запитання». Питання не лише в Раді; в будь-якому реченні «запитання» можна замінити на «питання» (хоч це не найточніше слово, але неправильним речення не стане); а от навпаки («питання» на «запитання») — ні.

Comment: @Sasha, а можна джерело? Дякую.

Comment: питання/запитання — розрізнення працює в один бік насправді. Тобто, в сесійній залі можна порушити питання (не запитання!), а на цьому сайті питання й запитання — одне й те ж, їх можна задавати/ставити (що також одне й те ж). Задавати питання = запитувати, питати. Питати питання — тавтологія, але «будуть питання — питай» звучить краще, ніж «будуть питання — задавай».

Answer (score 6):

> Будуть [питання](http://sum.in.ua/s/pytannja) · проблеми · [запитання](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapytannja) — [звертайся](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvertatysja)!
>   Будуть проблеми — [запитуй](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapytaty)!
>   Будуть [питання](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search.php?fullname=%E2%EE%EF%F0%EE%F1) — [задай](http://sum.in.ua/s/zadaty) · [завдай](http://sum.in.ua/s/zavdaty) · [порушуй](http://sum.in.ua/s/porushuvaty) · [висувай](http://sum.in.ua/s/vysuvaty)!
>   Будуть [запитання](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search.php?fullname=%E7%E0%EF%F0%EE%F1) · [запити](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81&highlight=on) — [став](http://sum.in.ua/s/stavyty) · [подай](http://sum.in.ua/s/podaty) · [вдайся](http://sum.in.ua/s/udatysja)!

---

Звідки *проблема*?

> <sup>Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980) ¬ [*проблема*](http://sum.in.ua/s/problema)</sup>
>   **Проблема**, и, *жін*. Складне теоретичне або практичне питання, що потребує вирішення. *— Нехай мене господь боронить, щоб я бралася за таку проблему, котрої закінчення непримінно [неодмінно]* ([Ольга Кобилянська](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%AE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0), III, 1956, 77); *Вона, моя маленька донька, ще не розуміється на складних проблемах людськості* ([Олесь Досвітній](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9), Вибр., 1959, 13).
>
> **Проблема номер один** — питання, що має найважливіше життєве значення і потребує якнайшвидшого розв'язання. *Проблема номер один сьогоднішнього господарювання — комплексна механізація* ([Знання та праця](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8F), 7, 1971, 9); *Розвідувачі надр проникають у найглухіші і найпустельніші місця, де проблемою номер один стає добування води* ([Вечірній Київ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2), 5.III 1971, 2).

---

> <sup>[УЛІФ НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/dictua.aspx) ¬ *питання* ⇒ Синонімія</sup>
>   **Питання** *яке, про кого-що* (те, що вимагає уваги, обговорення, розв'язання тощо), **[квестія](http://sum.in.ua/s/kvestija)** *яка, книжн.*, **проблема** *яка, чого* (складне). *Дослідники присвячують велику увагу саме питанню про звʼязки „Слова“ з народнопоетичною творчістю* [(Максим Рильський)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87); *Вона займалася живо „жіночою квестією“, мріяла про цілковиту самостійність* [(Ольга Кобилянська)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%AE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0); *Перед науковою медициною виникають нові проблеми: активна профілактика і лікування старості* (з газети).

---

> [Запитання не задають, а ставлять](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/66.htm)
>
> Семантичні відмінності є … у слів **питання** та запитання. Перше з них уживаємо тоді, коли йдеться про якусь справу, *проблему*, що потребує розв’язання чи дослідження; пункт документа, порядку денного. Найчастіше воно виступає у сполученні з дієсловом **порушувати**, рідше — **ставити**, **висувати** (в значенні “пропонувати для обговорення, вивчення”). Але заміну *порушувати* на *піднімати* (“Доповідач піднімав важливі питання...”) в сучасній літературній мові сприймають як стилістично невдалу.
>
> У граматичній термінології також уживається питання, а не запитання. Знак питання, а не знак запитання, питальне речення, а не запитальне.
>
> **Запитання** — це звернення до кого-небудь, щоб з’ясувати щось; вимога, прохання з приводу чогось; запит. “Несподіване запитання Богдана збентежило Гордія” (Дмитро Ткач). Кореспонденція на пошту надходить “до вимоги” її адресатом, або до запитання.
>
> Запитанням може бути і звернення, яке не потребує відповіді. То так зване риторичне запитання — прийом красномовства, художній засіб образної мови.
>
> Не можна поєднувати іменник запитання з дієсловом *задавати*, для цього є більш прийнятне **ставити**: “Капітан сміється, а Ліна Яцуба, не зводячи з нього своїх серйозних очей, ставить йому своє запитання” (Олесь Гончар). У значенні “звернення, що потребує відповіді” не слід уживати замість запитання слово питання, бо це суперечить мовним нормам.
>
> Підготував [Борис РОГОЗА](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), ”Хрещатик”

---

[Доповнення](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/472/)

Comment: а питання можна *задавати*?

Comment: СУМ мовляє що так, погляньте на посилання питання(1) й задай(1). А [OCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/) такого не рекомендує. Але тут „задавати питання“ близьке до „задавати проблеми“ чи „незручність“, а не кальковане „задавати запитання“. СУМ цього пітверджує, щоправда наполовину — там все-таки є „запитання“ в дужках.

Comment: із СУМом варто бути дуже обережно

Comment: Знаю. Але порівняння _питання_ з _проблемою_ чи вирішення цього й те, що _задавати_ більше має негативний окрас, є всюди.

Answer (score 2):

Ну по-перше, запитання і питання можуть бути синонімами згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapytannja). Гадаю, що можливі такі варіанти:

**Будуть запитання - звертайся** (бо із запитаннями звертаються, прикдад: Всі звертаються до Хоми з однаковим запитанням).

Варіант із взято прямо із СУМу:

> Коли з'являться у вас запитання... виникнуть якісь непорозуміння ...або надибаєте на чудернацькі речі чи там перешкоди, прошу негайно
> до мене

Тобто:

**Коли з'являться у вас запитання, прошу негайно до мене.**

Чи

**Виникнуть непорозуміння - спитаєш мене**

Answer (score 0):

Питання зазвичай виникають. Тож "виникнуть питання - задаси".

Comment: а хіба в українській мові є слово `задаси` ?

Comment: @Swartex, є: [орфографічний словник УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=задати) (офіційний вхід [тут](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)), [тлумачний словник СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=28890&page=958).

Comment: Пропоную ще такий варінат (із власного повсякденного вжитку): `Виникнуть питання – звертайся`.